# Passing variables to a Perl subroutine

Tags: perl

I would like to pass the following variables to subroutine mySubroutine, `$name, $age` and then this multidimensional array:

```
$name = "jennifer";
$age = 100;

$list[0][0] = "TEST NAME 2";
$list[0][1] = "TEST GROUP 2";
$[0][2] = 10;

$[1][0] = "TEST NAME 2";
$[1][1] = "TEST GROUP 2";
$[1][2] = 2;
```

Subroutine:

```
sub mySubroutine
{

}
```

I have tried `$_[0]`, and `@_`, but I don't seem to get the variables passed to the subroutine correctly.

Comment: I don't see any $name or $age. How are you calling the subroutine?

Comment: your example code misses some variables and most important- the function call.

Comment: did you even write like this `mySubroutine($name, $age, \@multidimensional_array)`?

Comment: Please flag the correct answer.

Comment: http://perl101.org/subroutines.html

Answer (score 27):

There are several ways to do it (like most things in Perl). I personally do it like this:

```
sub mySubroutine
{
    # Get passed arguments
    my ($name, $age, $refList) = @_;

    # Get the array from the reference
    my @list = @{$refList};
    # Good to go
}

# You need to pass @list as reference, so you 
# put \@list, which is the reference to the array
mySubroutine($name, $age, \@list);
```

Comment: It is better to use an array reference in your sub than to make a copy, unless you specifically need the copy for something.

Comment: Agreed but I don't know if the OP wants to modify the original array or not.

Comment: You're welcome. Don't forget the flag the answer as correct and welcome to SO :)

Answer (score 6):

Another way, which passes the array by reference, but then makes a copy of it to avoid changing the original when you edit it.

```
sub mySubroutine
{
    ## Retrieve name
    my $name = shift;

    ## Retrieve age
    my $age = shift;

    ## Retrieve list reference
    my $refList = shift;

    ## De-reference the list's scalar
    my @list = @{$refList};
    # Good to go
}

## Function call
mySubroutine($name, $age, \@list);
```

For a better understanding, please refer to [perlsub](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html) (Perl subroutines).

Comment: If you're doing it like this, better: `my $name = shift; my $age = shift;`... etc.

Answer (score 6):

Another option, as long as you are only passing one array, is to pass it normally by value as the last element:

```
sub scalars_and_one_array {
    my $name = shift;
    my $age = shift;

    foreach my $element (@_)
    {
       # Do something with the array that was passed in.
    }
}

scalars_and_one_array($name,$age,@array);
```

However, it is most efficient to avoid any additional copy of the array by only using a reference within the sub. This does mean that changes to the array in the sub affect the original, however:

```
sub array_by_ref {
    my $array_ref = shift;

    foreach my $element (@$array_ref)
    {
       # Changing $element changes @original_array!
    }
}

array_by_ref(\@original_array);
```