# Perl's XML::SemanticDiff - Getting the attribute value when there is a difference

Tags: xml, perl, whitespace

Apologies in advance for this question, I'm new to Perl.

I'm comparing two XML files using [XML::SemanticDiff](http://search.cpan.org/~shlomif/XML-SemanticDiff-1.0004/lib/XML/SemanticDiff.pm), with my own custom handler implemented. For the most part it works, but when I have two XML elements being compared that look like:

```
<tag attribute="value">
```

and

```
<tag attribute="  value  ">
```

I want to not count that as a difference. XML::SemanticDiff calls the element_value method. How do I get the value of the new and old attribute value so that I can trim out the whitespace and compare them? The documentation mentions that this can be done with the keepdata parameter (which I have added), but being new to Perl I don't understand how to then actually get the data when I'm in the element_value method.

Thanks in advance,
Thomas

Comment: I am not sure i understand your question correctly and i have no idea of XML::SemanticDiff but inside the method you can access all parameters that have been passed to its call via the `@_` array which will just contain all those parameters in order. See (among others) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15109917/passing-variables-to-a-perl-subroutine

Answer (score 0):

If you want enclosing spacing to be ignored in your XML attributes, I suggest that you just remove it before trying to compare documents.

The following uses [`XML::LibXML`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML%3a%3aLibXML) to remove spacing from an embedded XML document, but you could adapt this to an XML File as well.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::LibXML;

my $dom = XML::LibXML->load_xml(IO => \*DATA);

for my $attr ($dom->findnodes('//@*')) {
    my $string = $attr->getValue();
    if ($string =~ s/\A\s+|\s+\z//g) {
        $attr->setValue($string);
    }
}

print $dom->toString();

__DATA__
<root>
<tag attribute="  value  "/>
</root>
```

Outputs:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
<tag attribute="value"/>
</root>
```